# Color cell in calendar view

Tags: android, calendarview

I use calendarView and now I want to change a background color in some calender cells. How can I do this? Or maybe somebody knows how to setting a listener in some cell in view?
I tried like this:

```
(ListView) calendar.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

to find a list in widget, some id was back, but listener doesn't works. Same problem when I want to click on current day in view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android CalendarView for Showing Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556254/android-calendarview-for-showing-events)

Comment: Try to use https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView, it works great. I switched from CalendarView to CompactCalendarView, and it solved most of my problems.