# Android CalendarView - How to I have different colors on various dates?

Tags: android, calendarview

I would like to use the CalendarView calendar to mirrow another central calendar. So all I basicly need is to have/store the data myself and then at least visually markup the Android CalendarView with which dates there are appointments/events.

However, how do I change color for dates where I have appintments/events? (Or how do I tell CalendarView which dates I have appointsments/events, so it highlight those dates)

Comment: Post your sample code what you are working with, we can help you up to some extent after seeing the code, we cannot write the whole code.And have you tried this  android:weekNumberColor? Check this link for more help http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

Comment: I need a way to set colors for specific dates/cells. I have not been able to find any reference for that. There are a few SO's trying to the same like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393189/color-cell-in-calendar-view but none found any answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android CalendarView for Showing Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556254/android-calendarview-for-showing-events)